# Connect VB 6.0 application to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, vb6

Currenly I am using Oracle 9i Lite Client to connect my VB 6.0 application to Oracle database. The Oracle 9i Lite Client  is installed on all the user's machine. (around 200)

The VB 6.0 application also needs to talk to SQL Server 2000 database

I am trying to think for replacement of Oracle 9i  Lite client so that I can bring down the overall cost by removing Oracle 9i Lite Client from all the user's machine and replacing it with some opensource or cheaper option which allows me to connect to Oracle database without loosing connectivity to SQL Server 2000.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the Instant Client:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html

Comment: Looks promising - I would suggest "ODAC" version which includes "Oracle Provider for OLE DB". This part of the Oracle developer help explains how to use that with VB6 and ADO. You should be able to switch to SQL server just by changing the connection string.  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95498/using.htm#1014442